# Not able to find Reset Security token option in Salesforce

Tags: security, salesforce, access-token

I am not able to find the Reset Security token Option under the settings page in any of my sandbox instances. And I am not sure why this is happening. [image]Can someone please let me know how to find it. Or if I am missing out on anything.

I am attaching the screenshot of how my setting page menu looks right now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have login IP ranges defined. See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331668&type=1&mode=1

Try if you can force navigate to https://yourdomain.lightning.force.com/lightning/settings/personal/ResetApiToken/home to reset it anyway.